# 2 UITableViews in 1 ViewController. Set Delegate & DataSource to different UITableViewController file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

So I have two UITableViews in my ViewController, how do I set the delegate & datasource of the second one to that of another UITableViewController file.

For the second one, I'm currently creating it like this

```
 //now add our second tableview
UITableView *addPapersTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)];

addPapersTableView.dataSource = self;
addPapersTableView.delegate = self;
[addPapersView addSubview:addPapersTableView];
```

And due to the `self` bit, its obvious pulling data and being delegated from the same file.
Do I do something like `#import "AddMoreTableViewController.h"` and then something?

Really new to Objective C,

greatly appreciated,

Dex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your import as you suggested:

```
#import "AddMoreTableViewController.h"
```

Be sure to create an instance of it, then set **it** as the delegate/datasource of your other table.  Here's a rough example (I'll leave the memory management and semantics up to you):

```
AddMoreTableViewController *controller = [AddMoreTableViewController alloc] init];
myOtherTableView.datasource = controller;
myOtherTableView.delegate = controller;
```

You must ensure that you are implementing the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in `AddmoreTableViewController`.

Answer (score 5):

You complicate your life.

```
firstTableView.dataSource = self;
firstTableView.delegate = self;

secondTableView.dataSource = self;
secondTableView.delegate = self;
```

all methods of the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols have a UITableView* parameter, so you can handle both table views.
In example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == firstTableView) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
         return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, simplify your life :)

Comment: Double agreed, while Jeremy answered my question in this instance, your answer is great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could write a `tag` for this second `UITableView` & in the delegates handle different tables differently based on their `tag`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView.tag == 1)
        //handle table 1 here.
    else if(tableView.tag == 2)
        //handle table 2 here.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't know about this! While Jeremy answered my question in this instance, I appreciate your answer and look into `tag` :) Thank you!